# How does file recovery software work?

Tags: data-recovery

How do these file and folder recovery programs work? What is the best recovery software?

Comment: This would've been an interesting question had it only the first part. This wy it's just gonna be a list of programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this tool also:

http://the-undelete.com/windows_partition_recovery.php

http://www.datarecovery.ca/hard-drive-recovery.html

Answer (score 6):

When you delete a file, in fact, it's only the address of the file that's deleted from the files table.

So if you scan the not addressed space on your drive, you could find the deleted files. And if no other files was write in the same place, you can recover it.

(So if you have files to recover you shouldn't do anything else before and stop all process that can write to the disk, even the os itself if it's on the same partition)

I have no particular recommendation, they basically all does the same thing, only aesthetic and accessory features differentiate them...

Comment: This is the only answer that really answers the important question.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only true for some file systems on some OSes. I imagine the answer assumes Windows but there is nothing in either the question or the answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva). It's free

Answer (score -1):

I use [Symantec Ghost](http://www.symantec.com/norton/ghost) for recovery when I already have an Image of that "broken" computer.

I also like [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/enterprise/), not played a lot with but definitely a good backup/rescue software.

You can also use the Windows built-in backup software, depends which OS you have.

Hope this will help you!

David.

Comment: I do not say About Backup Software.I say About Recovery Software.

Comment: If you want to recover something... you need a backup of that thing... right? If not... Computer's brand Recovery CD is what you'd need.

Comment: This is not what the user is looking for at all.